# Symfony2 Translation - Double underscores in generated YML files & other issues

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I am using this to generate my translation files

```
php bin/console translation:update --force --output-format=yml it JakeNameOfBundle
```

This generates a like this

```
Register: __Register
Blog: __Blog
'Why?': '__Why?'
'Your message has been sent, thank you.': '__Your message has been sent, thank you.'
'Next on the Development List': '__Next on the Development List'
'Supported Game Systems': '__Supported Game Systems'
'Toggle navigation': '__Toggle navigation'
'Game Systems': '__Game Systems'
Home: __Home
Login: __Login
My: __My
```

A couple of questions;

1. Why is everything prefixed with __ (double underscores). If I leave them in then they appear on my site during translations which seems wrong and they therefore then need remove manually.
2. Can I change the single quotes to double quotes. A lot of other languages use single quotes within words
3. Can I ensure that everything is always wrapped in some sort of quote - it seems that single words are not wrapped at all.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a --prefix option to this command which default to "__" ; it should be possible to set it to an empty string.
As for the quoting, from what I've seen, it seems to be hardcoded into Symfony's yaml dumper (Symfony\Component\Yaml\Inline) which determines by itself if the string requires quoting, and if it needs to be double quotes ; I don't think it can be changed by configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know what the `__` is meant for though? The quoting I can cope with, its just annoying for translators.

Comment: I suppose it's used to determine if a string has already been translated or not ; in your example, a translator reading the file and seeing "Game Systems" without the underscore would not know that it is a new string that was generated automatically and still needs to be translated, and not an already translated key that was defined voluntarily as "Game System"

Comment: Make sense, seems a bit _hacky_

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I think the underscores indicate an error in the translation. Words that do not exist usually revert to the default locale and are not prefixed with underscores

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem appeared after updating a translations with a console command. For some reason a few string were generated wrong and placed in `app/Resources/translations` (I have them somewhere else normally). Simply removing those files solved the problem.